# Enrollment Challenge to retrieve UDID from iPhone

Tags: ios, udid, ota

Ad hoc testing facilities like [TestFlight](http://testflight.com) and [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net) use a part of the iOS OTA enrollment process to retrieve UDIDs (and possibly other device information, such as device type).

How do these services achieve this? I've already figured out how to provide an initial "profile service" payload to send to the phone. I receive a valid response from the phone via a POSt request. After that, I'm clueless, I keep getting an "Invalid profile" error.

What am I supposed to send back? Do I really have to set up a complete SCEP process (highly doubtful)?

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to set up a complete SCEP process. It is documented by Apple with sample ruby code on this URL: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I believe this is true for TestFlight and HockeyApp, but whatismyudid .com doesn't seem to use SCEP since it does not install a profile containing payloads like a WebClip, it seems to skip this step but still seems to deliver a valid request/response cycle.

Comment: Finally! After receiving the POST request from the device, one can simple issue a 301 redirect. This seems to fulfill the device's requirements and allows for storing the UDID.