# How does TestFlightApp know what device I'm using via the web?

Tags: ios, udid, testflight

We use [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/builds/) to test our iOS App binaries internally and with beta testers.

When TestFlight sends out an email alert to a user that a test binary is available, the web page it sends them to automatically knows if the user is using a registered device, but it seems to figure this out while in Safari. How is it doing this?

It has to match up UDIDs that we've supplied to their tool (via their website), but I was under the impression that websites could not grab data like UDIDs.  How is TestFlight figuring that out?

Comment: What of you mean by "knows if the user is using a registered device", right on the page or during ipa installation ?

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear - right on the page.  These are devices that have never visited testflightapp.com before loading up this page for the first time, yet it seems to know if this device is valid via visiting the page alone.

Comment: would be a public url sample possible ?

Comment: This has been asked before: 

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520407/enrollment-challenge-to-retrieve-udid-from-iphone
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781314/getting-a-device-udid-from-mobileconfig

Answer (score 4):

When registering a device with an account and installing the testflight profile. It then will store the UDID information it received via the profile installation process in a session (and probably a cookie) which then can be accessed from the same website URL. So whenever you go back to the website it checks for the stored information.

This is roughly how it is done, detailed implementation can only be answered by the developers.

Comment: I believe his question is "How is the TestFlight site getting the device UDID".

Comment: I agree with @ccculus. I also need to know how the TestFlight is grabbing device UDID. Do anyone find a solution to this question? Please answer.

Comment: The answer is explaining exactly that: by having the user install the Testflight configuration profile that procedure can send the UDID to a server. Here is the full documentation for what can be done with configuration profiles: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html