# Apple OTA and MDM enrollment via web header

Tags: ios, mdm, ota

I'm trying to setup a basic mdm server. Until now I configured the devices using a usb cable, but now I'd like to try an OTA installation of the mdm profile. I found some instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/iPhoneOTAConfiguration.pdf

What I would like to know is if there is some way to skip step 2, that is avoiding using SCEP during the enrollment (since this is just for testing, the idea would be to insert step two later).

The closest answer I could get was this: [Enrollment Challenge to retrieve UDID from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520407/enrollment-challenge-to-retrieve-udid-from-iphone)

but it isn't clear in the comments wheter the SCEP step can be avoided altogheter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, for what I was trying to do it was enough to send out the response to the enrollment with Content-type: application/x-apple-aspen-config header set and the profile in the body of the response. The profile then just installs itself on the device, enabling mdm if configured accordingly.